# Pictures of Chometz on Pesach

Tags: passover, see-sight-vision-blind, chametz-leaven

Is viewing pictures of Chometz allowed on Pesach? To be more specific this would be in reference to an article or event.

Comment: AJ, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question! I like your pic. Chag Sameach Vekasher.

Comment: And what about smelling chometz? there seems to be much more of a problem with deriving benefit in that case.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Mishna Brurah advises against sniffing any non-kosher food -- why tempt yourself?  As for "deriving benefit", the Talmud concludes that sound and light aren't "tangible benefits", but smell is.  I don't know how that works vis-a-vis chometz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely not assur. In fact seeing **actual** chometz is not assur either.

Comment: Right; the obligation is "no chometz shall be seen in your possession"; this isn't about seeing chometz; it's about owning it.  Common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between viewing chometz and smelling chometz is whether you get a benefit from it or not. As people, in general, don't get a benefit of seeing a picture of a loaf of bread, this should not be a problem. On the other hand, there IS a concept of getting a benefit from smelling (for example, making a blessing on the spices during havdalah and taking a whiff). If you happen to pass by a bakery by accident (or there is no other alternative than passing said bakery on the way to home or shul) and you get a whiff of bread, there shouldn't be a problem. But if you walk to a bakery to take in the smells, you might be violating a rabbinical ruling, in that you're getting a benefit from smelling bread on Pesach.

Comment: Barry Hammer, hello and welcome to Judaism.SE! Thanks for contributing your recent streak of _halacha_-related contributions. See you around.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I'm able to contribue to something where I actually have some knowledge I can bring to the table ;)

Comment: +1. This matches what I've heard from in the name of some _t'shuva_ book or other (I forget which), but citations are always useful.